# c# modular executive dashboard opensource project

Tags: c#, open-source, projects-and-solutions, dashboard

I am looking for a tool or project, preferably in c# that will allow me to easily make and create custom dashboards for various departments.

I need to able to specify different datasources that will supply the info needed to generate the dashboard look and feel.

Some of the datasource will be sql database, others are wcf or asmx webservices, excel spread sheets and csv files.

It would also be helpful if i can specify thresholds for the different data so it shows as green or red based ont he value and the set threshold.

Some of the kind of data i need to display are number of sales, stock/inventory levels, credits and debits on the financial systems, bandwidth consumption etc.

Anything ideas, projects or tools that could make even a fraction of this work would be appreciated.

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are looking for open source i think Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 can be one option, if cost is not the limitation you can also go ahead with MOSS 2007.

Here is one list for open source software in c#

[Open Source c#](http://csharp-source.net/)

Comment: + 1 for the provided link!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Kalitte Dynamic Dashboards](http://www.dynamicdashboards.net).

It has an open source widget library, database & browser independent.